# Design constrains for non-aerobraking re-entry vehicle?

Tags: reentry, design, aerobraking

Currently, getting from orbit to ground always involves aerobraking to shed lots of orbital velocity. This is a dangerous, stressful maneuver which also cannot be repeated with same vehicle due to the heat shield being destroyed by the re-entry.

What would be design constraints for an orbital descent vehicle that avoids air-braking and instead slows down gradually using its own power? How sci-fi is it?

Some points about the requirements on the vehicle:

- No excessive Gs during descend. Make it safe and relatively comfortable for non-trained civilians.
- No aerobraking and thus no heat shield. I assume it would require the descent vehicle to be highly aerodynamic.
- What kind of engine would be necessary? What would be its characteristics?
- Where and how would the engines be placed?
- Assuming current types of fuel, how much fuel would be needed to slow down for landing?
- Vehicle can be re-used multiple times, without need for significant maintenance or parts replacement.
- Is it possible to shed most of the orbital speed before entering atmosphere, without significant Gs?
- What would the re-entry trajectory and characteristics look like? How long would it take? How much time could be spent in space and how much in atmosphere?

This question is inspired by this [WorldBuilding question about designing a scifi ground-to-space transport](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/241448/what-is-the-best-design-for-trans-atmospheric-cargo-ship/241467).

Comment: Your question is based on a flawed premise, re-usable heat shields exist, and it's really not that stressful.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10367/is-powered-descent-from-orbit-a-viable-method-of-reentry-on-bodies-with-an-atmos/10369#10369

Comment: "Vehicle can be re-used multiple times, without need for significant maintenance or parts replacement." This is very far from reality. A two stage rocket would be needed and the first stage would be lost. The second stage would need a lot of inspection before reuse.

Comment: "Is it possible to shed most of the orbital speed before entering atmosphere, without significant Gs?" This would be the perfect method to waste  a huge amount of fuel.

Comment: "which also cannot be repeated with same vehicle due to heat shield being destroyed by the re-entry." Space shuttle begs to differ

Comment: @OrganicMarble And the X-37, and Starship. Even Dragon's ablative heat shield was designed to withstand multiple reentries, and the capsules have been reused including components of the heat shield (though not the actual ablative tiles, that I'm aware of).

Answer (score 4):

There are limited options for slowing down from orbital velocity. Use the air or use a rocket. Rocket it is then.

Fundamentally, slowing down and speeding up is exactly the same thing. That means a rocket big enough to slow something down from orbital velocity is just as big as something needed for launching stuff into space.

And you need an awfully big rocket to launch something into space. Take the Ariane 5, for instance. A 760 ton rocket to launch a 16 ton payload. A ratio of approximately 50 to 1.

So to slow down a little reentry capsule of say 3 tons, you need a 150 ton, probably multi stage, rocket, *in space!*

To get *that* rocket up there in the first place, you need a 7,500 ton rocket, larger than any rocket ever build. For just a single capsule.

You're effectively taking the [tyranny of the rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation), and squaring the problem with using propulsive means of landing.

---

> What kind of engine would be necessary? What would be it's characteristics?

To bring down the mass ratio to practical levels, you will need something that has both high thrust and high exhaust velocity (efficiency). We do not have this. Chemical rockets have an exhaust velocity that is too low, and ion engines have too little thrust to do the burn in time before crashing into the ground. Even nuclear thermal rockets have too poor efficiency for this to be practical. What's left is sci-fi tech like fusion rockets.

Comment: Actually it would be worse than the rocket equation - Can't leave parts of the rocket behind when descending in this scenario